# Angular 2 textarea won't accept value from JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I have an Angular 2 app that has an input textarea field:

`<textarea id="projectDescription" required [(ngModel)]="projectDescription" [formControl]="createNewForm.controls['projectDescription']" style="margin-bottom:-2%;width:50%;"></textarea>`

We also have a testing team that uses the Selenium testing framework for automated testing.  They are trying to inject a value into the textarea to submit the form by using

```
$("#projectDescription").val("Test value");
```

However, the textarea's text is not getting updated (we've also used other iterations of adding text i.e text(), innerHTML = ).  It works fine for other input types such as 'text', it is only the textarea that is not getting updated.  Is this a known issue, and is there any solution for it?

**EDIT**: I should also note that I'm not even able to update the value in my local console on the site.  But when I remove the Angular 2 specific attributes (i.e ng-object ng-class) I am able to update the value, so there is something going on with the interaction between the Angular framework and JQuery.

Comment: Is it possible to remove any of the Angular attributes to fix it?

Comment: `I should also note that I'm not even able to update the value in my local console on the site.` I tried it and it works for me. Can you provide an example where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use JQuery when you're using Angular. There may be SOME use cases where you may need to use JQuery, but those situations will be very rare, if they happen at all. Instead, put a local element ref on the html tag like so (the `#projectDescription`):

```
<textarea #projectDescription id="projectDescription" required [(ngModel)]="projectDescription" [formControl]="createNewForm.controls['projectDescription']" style="margin-bottom:-2%;width:50%;"></textarea>
```

And in your ts, get the `ElementRef` using `@ViewChild` like so:

```
@ViewChild('projectDescription') projectDescription: ElementRef;
```

Make sure you import `ViewChild` and `ElementRef` from `@angular/core`.

And manipulate the value of the textarea using:

```
this.projectDescription.nativeElement.value = "Whatever you want the value to be";
```

You can also `console.log(this.projectDescription)` to see exactly what else in the native element you can manipulate.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately, the testing framework is outside my Angular app.  There is no JQuery code in my app, we are using a Selenium webdriver to test submission, so the test code uses JQuery to drive the app flow, it doesn't access any internal Angular code.  I'm specifically looking for solutions on how to incorporate the JQuery testing framework :)

Comment: I see. I will leave my answer in for anybody who may read your question and think about it the way I did. But I might suggest you rephrase your question a little bit, because as it is, your question doesn't seem to actually have anything to do with the Angular part of your app, but how to use another external library in conjunction with Angular. As far as I can tell anyway.

Comment: Sorry!  The reason I mention Angular is that I know that the JQuery in my question will insert a value into a textarea, it's just specifically for my Angular 2 app it won't update the text in the textarea.

Comment: No need to apologize. Hopefully someone can answer your question. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Selenium. So good luck with that!